# Discord.py How to make next user's message a variable?

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "{")

1. @bot.command(pass_context = True)
2. async def hello(ctx): #I know that exactly this function can be made easier.
3.     ctx.send("Enter the name")
4.     #user's message without {hello
5.     ctx.send(f"Hello {#name from the previous line#}")
```

Comments for lines: 2. User enter {hello 3. Bot sends message (Enter the name) 4. User sends a message to chat without {hello, so there is a name only 5. Bot sends a message (Hello, {name})

What to put instead 4th and part of 5th line?

Answer (score 1):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

You need a `check()` method so you get the correct message object. Inside the check you define on what condition the message object would be correct. In your case the return should be changed to:

```
return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel
```